# ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, database, oracle, ora-00933

I need to convert MSSQL query to Oracle but end up with `SQL command not properly ended`.

Here is MSSQL query

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[trade] AS [Extent1]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 AS [C1] FROM
    [dbo].[findetail] AS [Extent2]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[transact] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[transact] = [Extent3].[transact]
    WHERE [Extent1].[trade] = [Extent2].[trade]
    AND 'ACCR' = [Extent3].[subledger]
    AND [Extent3].[date] = '2016-03-18T00:00:00'
)
```

Converting it to Oracle SQL I end with this.

```
SELECT * FROM trade Extent1
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 C1 FROM findetail Extent2
    JOIN transact Extent3
    ON Extent2.transact=Extent3.transact
    WHERE Extent1.trade=Extent2.trade 
    AND 'ACCR'=Extent3.subledger
    AND  Extent3.date='2016-03-18T00:00:00'
  );
```

and receive error above.

Comment: Date is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, delimit that column as `"date"`.

Comment: You can also remove the sub-query's column alias c1. Not needed at all.

Comment: Why are you giving your tables alias names such as `Extent1` instead of more meaningful abbreviations (or just the table name itself)?

Comment: While the date column name and format are issues, they shouldn't give that error. How are you executing this?

Answer (score 0):

Date formats are different in Oracle.  Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM trade Extent1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM findetail Extent2 JOIN
                   transact Extent3
                   ON Extent2.transact = Extent3.transact
              WHERE Extent1.trade = Extent2.trade AND
                    Extent3.subledger = 'ACCR' AND
                    Extent3."date" = DATE '2016-03-18'
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

`DATE` is a reserved word so needs to the surrounded in double quotes and, I am assuming that it is of `DATE` data type so you will probably need to convert the string:

```
SELECT *
FROM   trade t
WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   findetail f
                JOIN transact r
                ON f.transact = r.transact
         WHERE  t.trade   = f.trade 
         AND    'ACCR'    = r.subledger
         AND     r."DATE" = TO_DATE( '2016-03-18T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS' )
      );
```

If you just use the string in `r."DATE" = '2016-03-18T00:00:00'` then Oracle will implicitly try to convert the string literal using the `TO_DATE()` function with the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format mask. If they match then it will work but this is a client variable so can be changed and then the query will break without the code having changed (and be a pain to debug). The simple answer is to ensure that you compare date value by either using `TO_DATE()` and specifying the format mask (as per the query above) or to use an ANSI date literal `DATE '2016-03-18'` (which is independent of the NLS settings).